# Edited status of NSWindowController from separate undoManagers

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nsdocument, nswindowcontroller, nsundomanager

When an `NSWindowController` has an `NSDocument` assigned, its `edited` status is automatically set based on the current location in the undo/redo stack relative to when the document was last saved. It works great so that the "Edited" title of the window is automatically set when someone performs an undoable action since the last save.

In my case, I have multiple window controllers for the document, because I have multiple tabs that each control a segment of the data. So I want a separate undoManager for each window/tab so that the changes in one tab are not undone when the user hits undo in a separate tab. I.e., I need to have isolated undo managers.

This works fine, but since I'm not ever talking to the `NSDocument`'s undo manager, the edited status of the window is not being updated when I make undoable changes in any of the tabs. How can I signal to the document that I want its edited status to be contingent on the undo stack location for a number of other undo managers?

Comment: Did you try `updateChangeCount:`?

Comment: `updateChangeCount` on the document certainly works, but I need it to be contingent on the state of all the separate undo managers relative to when the document was last saved, so I don't have enough information to know what it should be set to.

Comment: That's a tough problem. I have a single document/window with sidebars that each have their own undo manager. I ended up overriding some window controller methods to create a kind of a "pile" of undoManagers. When a child undo manager gets used it becomes the "hot" undo manager, and satisfies requests until it's empty, then the next one in the "pile" takes over. It's ugly, and complicated, but it kind-of, sort-of, works in a "what you'd expect" sort of way. If you can't find a better solution, I can dig into mine and see if I can figure out what I did. :/

Comment: The change count counts changes. So I would expect `updateChangeCount:NSChangeDone` after a change, undo or redo and `updateChangeCount:NSChangeCleared` when the document is saved. Drawback: when everything is undone the document will still be edited.

Comment: Standard document based app design: Model object holds instance of nsundomanger (from document) and it registers undo action whenever model changes. Your design: model broken into separate pieces (per window) and each model has it's own undomanager from windowcontroller. You can always call setDocumentEdited: (terrible if your model knows about windowcontroller or you call it from wc) or updateChangeCount: (much better with weak document instance) inside your mini model. Sooner or later you will end up with app design issues (overlaping mini model objects).